# Rotating a plane around its edge on TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, asymptote, tikz-3d, tikz-calc

I'm trying to rotate the red plane in the right side around the its edge AB, the question is actually about rotating anything around a arbitrary path, I know the `rotate around` command and that I can use it to rotate around an arbitrary point or axis and I actually used it to attempt two rotations around the point C in the figure, the failed results are the green planes, the intended results are the diagonal plane with the AD edge and the red plane on the xz plane, which I've drawn them in the old way.

I'm aware of the `tikz-3dplot` and `perspective` packages and the `canvas is x1x2 at x3=cte` syntax that can be used as a option as well, but I didn't really succeed in using them to achieve the result I want.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz, amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}%[canvas is zy plane at x=10]

\coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);
\coordinate (C) at (3,0,1.5);
\coordinate (D) at ($3*({(1-cos(45))},{cos(45)},1)$);
\coordinate (A) at (3,0,3);
\coordinate (B) at (3,0,0);

%XYZ axis
\draw[->] (O) -- (5,0,0) node[right] {x};
\draw[->] (O) -- (0,5,0) node[above] {y};
\draw[->] (O) -- (0,0,5.5) node[left] {z};

%Attempted point of rotation
\filldraw (C) circle (2.5pt) node[below right] {C};

%Red right plane
\filldraw[red, opacity=.5, rotate around={0:(C)}] (3,0,3) --++(0,0,-3) --++(0,3,0) node[right, midway, text opacity=1, black] {3} --++(0,0,3) -- cycle;

%Blue top plane
\filldraw[blue, opacity=.5] (0,3,3) --++(0,0,-3) --++(3,0,0) node[midway, above, text opacity=1] {3} --++(0,0,3) -- cycle;

%Cube's diagonal plane
\draw[fill=gray, opacity=.25, text = black] (3,0,3) --++(0,0,-3) --++(-3,3,0) --++(0,0,3) -- cycle;

%Actual rotation 1
\filldraw[purple, opacity=.4] (3,0,3) --++(0,0,-3) --++($cos(45)*(-3,3,0)$) --++(0,0,3) -- cycle;

%Actual rotation 2
\filldraw[purple, opacity=.5] (3,0,3) --++(0,0,-3) --++(-3,0,0) --++(0,0,3) -- cycle;

%Segment AD
\draw[very thick] (A) -- (D) node [left] {D};

%Failed rotation 1
\filldraw[green, opacity=.25, rotate around={45:(C)}] (3,0,3) --++(0,0,-3) --++(0,3,0) --++(0,0,3) -- cycle;

%Failed rotation 2
\filldraw[green, opacity=.25, rotate around={90:(C)}] (3,0,3) --++(0,0,-3) --++(0,3,0) --++(0,0,3) -- cycle;

%Intended axis of rotation
\draw[very thick] (A) node[below] {A} -- (B) node[above right] {B};

\node at (4,4,0) {
$
\bigl|\overline{AD}\bigr| = 3
$
};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE.

I'm drawing only four rectangles and the axes, as an example I hope it's enough.

You can draw the rectangles in planes parallel to XY, XZ and YZ (as you said) with the options `canvas is...` from `3d` library. For example, the red one:

```
\filldraw[red,opacity=0.5,canvas is yz plane at x=3]  (0,0) rectangle (3,3);
```

For the other planes you have to shift the origin, then rotate around the (new) z-axis and last set the canvas as the (new) xz plane. As this is for two planes it can be done in a `scope`:

```
\begin{scope}[shift={(3,0,0)},rotate around z=135,canvas is xz plane at y=0]
...
\end{scope}
```

Last, for the gray plane you could make an optional scale: `xscale={sqrt(2)}`.

A complete example:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1.618mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
%XYZ axis
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (5,0,0)   node[right] {x};
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,5,0)   node[above] {y};
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,5.5) node[left]  {z};
% Rotations
\begin{scope}[shift={(3,0,0)},rotate around z=135,canvas is xz plane at y=0]
  %Cube's diagonal plane
  \draw[fill=gray,opacity=0.25,xscale={sqrt(2)}] (0,0) rectangle (3,3);
  %Cube's diagonal plane (more usual alternative)
%  \draw[fill=gray,opacity=0.25] (0,0) rectangle ({3*sqrt(2)},3);
  %Actual rotation
  \draw[fill=purple,opacity=0.4] (0,0) rectangle (3,3);
\end{scope}
%Red right plane
\filldraw[red,opacity=0.5,canvas is yz plane at x=3]  (0,0) rectangle (3,3);
%Blue top plane
\filldraw[blue,opacity=0.5,canvas is xz plane at y=3] (0,0) rectangle (3,3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, I didn't even that I should rotate first then change the canvas, because reversing the order would affect the result, that's probably why it wasn't working, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple way with Asymptote. In 3D, we can define a plane P (as a parallelogram) ABCD by `P=plane(B-A,D-A,A)`, then using the transform `t=rotate(45,A,B)` (rotates 45 degrees around A--B) to get `t*P`.

This 3D transform `t` can be used for any 3D path. That is an advantage of 3D Asymptote over the library `3d` of TikZ.

[image]

```
// http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/
import three;
import graph3;
unitsize(1cm);
// obliqueX, obliqueY, obliqueZ or any others
//currentprojection=oblique;
currentprojection=orthographic(1.5,1,3,up=Y);

triple A=(3,0,3), B=(3,0,0);
real a=Cos(45);    // cosine in degrees
triple D=3*(1-a,a,1);

// the plane with the edges A--B and A--D
path3 P=plane(B-A,D-A,A);
draw(P,red);
draw(surface(P),red+opacity(.2));

// t rotates around A--B any path3 with 45 degrees 
transform3 t=rotate(45,A,B);
draw(t*P,blue);
draw(surface(t*P),blue+opacity(.2));

label("$A$",A,SW);
label("$B$",B,NE);
label("$D$",D,W);
axes3("$x$","$y$","$z$",min=O,max=(5,5,5),Arrow3);
```